# Python - add PYTHONPATH during command line module run

Tags: python, pythonpath

I want to run:

```
python somescript.py somecommand
```

But, when I run this I need `PYTHONPATH` to include a certain directory. I can't just add it to my environment variables because the directory I want to add changes based on what project I'm running. Is there a way to alter `PYTHONPATH` while running a script? Note: I don't even have a `PYTHONPATH` variable, so I don't need to worry about appending to it vs overriding it during running of this script.

Answer (score 199, accepted):

For Mac/Linux;

```
PYTHONPATH=/foo/bar/baz python somescript.py somecommand
```

For Windows, setup a wrapper `pythonpath.bat`;

```
@ECHO OFF
setlocal
set PYTHONPATH=%1
python %2 %3
endlocal
```

and call `pythonpath.bat` script file like;

```
pythonpath.bat /foo/bar/baz somescript.py somecommand
```

Comment: @İsmail - thanks. However, how can I do that while running a script from my command prompt? I'm not running Python, importing stuff, and running it manually.

Comment: On Mac/Linux you would do `PYTHONPATH=/foo/bar python somescript.py somecommand`

Comment: I tried `python -c"import sys;sys.path.append('/my/dir')"` and then `python myscript.py mycommand`, but it obviously doesn't share the path from the first interpreter session with the next. Ah, just saw your next comment, trying now... Didn't work on WinXP.

Comment: You need to setup a *.bat file to do this for you.

Comment: Sweet, I'm already using a .bat file for this, so I just added `set PYTHONPATH=D:/mydirectory/path` (ie, hardcoded, since I have a different .bat file for each project). Thanks a lot for the help. I hate setting actual environment variables on my computer and then having to change / delete them each day.

Comment: There is no `unset` environment variable command on Windows. Instead add a `setlocal` after the initial `echo off` and then an implicit `endlocal` will occur when the .bat script ends (and `PYTHONPATH` will be restored to its previous value).

Comment: On Windows if you want to *append* a path the existing `PYTHONPATH`, you might want to use `set PYTHONPATH=%PYTHONPATH%;%1`.

Comment: See [python docs](https://docs.python.org/3.7/using/windows.html#excursus-setting-environment-variables) as well.

Comment: This ans worked for mac/linux. I would also love to learn how to read this PYTHONPATH from a config file, and doing so on the command line too.

Answer (score 54):

```py
import sys
sys.path.append('your certain directory')
```

Basically sys.path is a list with all the search paths for python modules. It is initialized by the interpreter. The content of PYTHONPATH is automatically added to the end of that list.

Comment: or sys.path.insert(0,'/some/directory') to put it at the front of your path.  This allows your material to override other stuff that may already be on pythonpath.

Comment: I used this answer to run uninttest outside pydev-eclipse IDE.

Comment: `sys.path.append(r'D:\PyCharmProjects\cheese_shoppe')` example in Windows.

Answer (score 23):

If you are running the command from a POSIX-compliant shell, like `bash`, you can set the environment variable like this:

```
PYTHONPATH="/path/to" python somescript.py somecommand
```

If it's all on one line, the PYTHONPATH environment value applies only to that one command.

```
$ echo $PYTHONPATH

$ python -c 'import sys;print("/tmp/pydir" in sys.path)'
False
$ PYTHONPATH=/tmp/pydir python -c 'import sys;print("/tmp/pydir" in sys.path)'
True
$ echo $PYTHONPATH
```

Comment: Just what I was looking for, thanks a lot. For some reason running `python -c "import sys; sys.path.insert(0,'my/path'); import mymodule"` did not work.

Answer (score 3):

You can paste the following code in the `__init__.py` of the package from which you want to import:

```
import sys
from pathlib import Path

sys.path.insert(0, Path(__file__).parent)
```

Then you can import modules from that package as you would usually do.

```
import <module_name>

<module_name>.<method_on_module>()
```

```
Example:
import algorithms

algorithms.run_algo1()
```

Your IDE might underline the module name, but that won't be a problem when you run the Python interpreted.

Also, if you need to read the path, later on, you can do:

```
DIR_PATH = Path(sys.path[0])
```

Comment: thanks.. u have to stringify it i.e.  str(Path(__file__).parent)

Answer (score 2):

You may try this to execute a function inside your script

```
python -c "import sys; sys.path.append('/your/script/path'); import yourscript; yourscript.yourfunction()"
```

Answer (score 0):

This is for windows:

For example, I have a folder named "mygrapher" on my desktop. Inside, there's folders called "calculation" and "graphing" that contain Python files that my main file "grapherMain.py" needs. Also, "grapherMain.py" is stored in "graphing". To run everything without moving files, I can make a batch script. Let's call this batch file "rungraph.bat".

```
@ECHO OFF
setlocal
set PYTHONPATH=%cd%\grapher;%cd%\calculation
python %cd%\grapher\grapherMain.py
endlocal
```

This script is located in "mygrapher". To run things, I would get into my command prompt, then do:

```
>cd Desktop\mygrapher (this navigates into the "mygrapher" folder)
>rungraph.bat (this executes the batch file)
```

Comment: and how is this different from @İsmail 'cartman' Dönmez answer?

Answer (score 0):

this works on windows.

testpackage structure:

```
D:\testpackage_path\TESTPACKAGE
│   first.py
│   __init__.py
│
├───sub1
│   │   sub1a.py
│   │   sub1b.py
│   │   __init__.py
```

test_PYTHONPATH.py:

```
import os
from testpackage import first
from testpackage.sub1 import sub1a
print(f'PYTHONPATH={os.environ.get("PYTHONPATH")}')
first.first_method()
sub1a.sub1a_method1()
```

from the command line:

```
C:\>set PYTHONPATH=D:\testpackage_path && test_PYTHONPATH.py
PYTHONPATH=D:\testpackage_path 
running first_method()
running sub1a_method1()
```