# Running python unittest in the console

Tags: python, unit-testing, console

I have the follwoing package structure

```
my-base-project
-> package1
    __init__.py
    MyScript.py
-> test
    __init__.py
    TestMyScript.py
```

I'd like to run the `TestMyScript.py` in the console. Therefore I cd in to `my-base-project/test` and execute `python TestMyScript.py`. However, I'm getting the error:

```
user@computer:~/my-base-project/test$ python TestMyScript.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "TestMyScript.py", line 4, in <module>
    from package1 import MyScript
ImportError: No module named package1
```

How do I run these tests?

Comment: why don't you put TestMyScript.py in the same folder as package1 ?

Comment: Does `user@computer:~/my-base-project$ python test/TestMyScript.py` work?

Comment: No, `python test/TestMyScript.py` does not work. And I actually reluctant to copy a test file into a prodcution package.

Comment: Is my-base-project in your PYTHONPATH?

Answer (score 0):

From [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4580101/python-add-pythonpath-during-command-line-module-run), consider adding the directory you need to the PYTHONPATH:

```
 import sys
 sys.path.append('your certain directory')
```

Maybe you want to add the parent directory

```
sys.path.append('..')
```