# How can I import another module in the same parent directory?

Tags: python

I've got two files, `foo/a.py` with:

```
def haha():
    print("haha")
```

And also `bar/b.py` with:

```
import foo.a as a
```

I fail to run to run `b.py`, with:

```
> python bar/b.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bar/b.py", line 1, in <module>
    import foo.a
 ImportError: No module named 'foo'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I suggest reading https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/

Comment: I did, and this detail passed through.

Comment: Here you go again than: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python can only find modules on your PYTHONPATH. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4580101/python-add-pythonpath-during-command-line-module-run) for how to set it.

Modules can be at top level, or in a *package*. If you run python bar/b.py, the directory that b.py is in is implicitly added to the Python path. The directory that foo/ and bar/ are in is unknown to Python, let alone the one that contains a.py.

You can add './foo' to the PYTHONPATH. Then 'import a' will work.

If you want 'import foo.a' to work, then 'foo' must be a package, and it must be possible to find it. To do so, add '.' (the directory containing foo/' to the Pythonpath, and *place an empty file named `__init__.py` (note that's double underscores) in the same directory as a.py*. That makes foo a package, and foo.a a module in that package.

Answer (score 0):

yes add `__init__.py` at `../foo/` location.

and use following :

I have directory structure like: `/home/test/foo/a.py` and `/home/test/bar/b.py`

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/home/test')
from foo import a
try:sys.path.remove('/home/test')
except:pass
```