# Append to a remote environment variable for a command started via ssh on RO filesystem

Tags: bash, ssh, environment-variables

I can run a Python script on a remote machine like this:

```
ssh -t <machine> python <script>
```

And I can also set environment variables this way:

```
ssh -t <machine> "PYTHONPATH=/my/special/folder python <script>"
```

I now want to *append* to the *remote* `PYTHONPATH` and tried

```
ssh -t <machine> 'PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/my/special/folder python <script>'
```

But that doesn't work because `$PYTHONPATH` won't get evaluated on the remote machine.

There is a quite [similar question](https://superuser.com/questions/48783/how-can-i-pass-an-environment-variable-through-an-ssh-command) on SuperUser and the accepted answer wants me to create an environment file which get interpreted by `ssh` and [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4580101/python-add-pythonpath-during-command-line-module-run) which can be solved by creating and copying a script file which gets executed instead of `python`.

This is both **awful** and requires the target file system to be writable (which is not the case for me)!

Isn't there an elegant way to either pass environment variables via `ssh` or provide additional module paths to Python?

Comment: Is `PYTHONPATH` actually set on the remote machine, what does `ssh -t <machine> 'echo $PYTHONPATH'` say?

Answer (score 1):

How about using `/bin/sh -c '/usr/bin/env PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/.../ python ...'` as the remote command?

EDIT (re comments to prove this should do what it's supposed to given correct quoting):

```
bash-3.2$ export FOO=bar
bash-3.2$ /usr/bin/env FOO=$FOO:quux python -c 'import os;print(os.environ["FOO"])'
bar:quux
```

Comment: Seems to have no effect for me. `PYTHONPATH` has still the same value. When I run `/bin/sh -c '/usr/bin/env PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/data/ echo $PYTHONPATH'` on my local machine, `PYTHONPATH` is printed unmodified

Comment: That's because `$PYTHONPATH` there gets expanded before the env call by your shell. I'll augment my answer -- hold on.

Answer (score 1):

WFM here like this:

```
$ ssh host 'grep ~/.bashrc -e TEST'
export TEST="foo"
$ ssh host 'python -c '\''import os; print os.environ["TEST"]'\'
foo
$ ssh host 'TEST="$TEST:bar" python -c '\''import os; print os.environ["TEST"]'\'
foo:bar
```

Note the:

- single quotes around the entire command, to avoid expanding it locally

  - embedded single quotes are thus escaped in the signature `'\''` pattern (another way is `'"'"'`)
- double quotes in assignment (only required if the value has whitespace, but it's good practice to not depend on that, especially if the value is outside your control)
- avoiding of `$VAR` in command: if I typed e.g. `echo "$TEST"`, it would be expanded by shell before replacing the variable

  - a convenient way around this is to make var replacement a separate command:

    ```
    $ ssh host 'export TEST="$TEST:bar"; echo "$TEST"'
    foo:bar
    ```