# Import package within sub-package

Tags: python-2.7

I'm trying to understand how this work but I'm really confused.

I created a package **"parent"** under ***C:\script\test with empty __init__.py***

**parent\testfunc.py**

```
def return_2():
    return 2
```

Then, a couple sub packages with ***empty __init__.py***

**parent\sub\subsub\testsubsub.py**

```
from parent import testfunc

def print_2():
    print(testfunc.return_2())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print_2()
```

- If I execute this within PyCharm, it works. I get 2.
- Open CMD, add C:\script\test to %PATH%, it cannot find the parent module
- CMD with %PATH% set and -m flag, it says I cannot import by filename

Why do I get different result? Why could it not find the package if it's already added to the **%PATH%?** Why did it work in **PyCharm?**

Edit - I am unsure if the provided link was addressing the same issue since the OP was able to import his package while I cannot. Additional searching brought me to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4580101/python-add-pythonpath-during-command-line-module-run) which suggested %PYTHONPATH% instead of %PATH% and that seems to do the trick.

Comment: Don't put scripts inside packages, scripts are executed as `__main__` and *are not in a package*.

Comment: In this case, you need to put `C:\script\test` on your Python module search path, explicitly, so to `PYTHONPATH`, not `PATH`. There are no mechanisms that would put `parent` anywhere on the search path just because you created sub-packages. Your script has no package context.

Comment: What is package context? Is it how you set up \__init__.py? I'm looking at numpy as example and I admit I'm totally lost.

Comment: You didn't include how you ran with the `-m` flag; for `python -m`, a **module** name is expected, so `parent.sub.subsub.testsubsub`.

Comment: `__init__.py` files in the same directory as a script have no meaning, no.