# pytest: source files and test files in a different directory

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest

I have a project, which consists out of source code and test code. The source code is stored in one directory, and my tests are stored in another.

```
root
  |- src
  | |- pkg
  | | | - __init__.py
  | | | - src1.py
  | | | - src2.py
  |- test
  | |- tests_for_pkg
  | | | - __init__.py
  | | | - first_test.py
  | | | - second_test.py
```

When I'm running my tests, I am required to import all of my source code in the `_test.py` files.

```
from pkg.src1 import src1
from pkg.src2 import src2
```

I would like to run all of my tests in one go using `python -m pytest <tests>` or running a script, but I keep getting errors about my imports.

I had issues with my Python path before in my Eclipse IDE, so I opted to use relative paths and add them as an external library to the Python path based on a relative path in my folder structure.

For example, my include path would be:

```
../src/pkg
```

How can I implement such a relative path in the Python command line/as a Python script?

EDIT: Using the provided links, I was able to get my test working by adding a `conftest.py` file and appending the location of my code.

However, my actual project has a massive source tree as follows:

```
root
| - projectdir
| | - projectone
| | | - datedir
| | | | - trunk
| | | | | - sd
| | | | | | - code
| | | | | | | src
| | | | | | | - pkg
| | | | | | | | - __init__.py
| | | | | | | | - src1.py
| | | | | | | | - src2.py
| | | | | | - model
| | | | | | | - testdir
| | | | | | | | - testware
| | | | | | | | | - unittest_pkg
| | | | | | | | | | - test
| | | | | | | | | | | - tests_for_pkg
| | | | | | | | | | | | - first_test.py
| | | | | | | | | | | | - second_test.py
```

`conftest.py` first source tree (allows me to run my tests from the test dir):

```
import sys
sys.path.append('..\..\src')
```

`conftest.py` second source tree (can't run any tests from any dir):

```
import sys
sys.path.append('..\..\..\..\..\..\..\code\src')
```

When I use the exact same method as before, it doesn't work. Does `conftest.py` have a limit on how far it can search for the `src` directory?

EDIT: Solved with help from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4580101/python-add-pythonpath-during-command-line-module-run) question.

I ended up making a batch script which looks for any files ending in `test.py` and runs them.

```
@echo off
for /r %%i in (*test.py) do (
    setlocal
    set PYTHONPATH=../../../src/pkg
    python -m pytest --junitxml=%%~pi/JUnit_%%~ni.xml %%i
    endlocal
)

@RD /S /Q .pytest_cache
```

Answer (score 5):

Why not add current directory to `PYTHONPATH` before running pytest?

```
export PYTHONPATH="$PYTHONPATH:$PWD"
```

Alternatively, you can add directory to PYTHONPATH in test `.py` by:

```
import sys
import os
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath('../src/pkg'))
```