# Why is my script working, when I execute it manually, but with crontab it doesn't work?

Tags: python, cron, debian-stretch

My **Raspberry Pi 3** (running debain stretch) is connected to a relay board.

Two Python Scripts are turning it on/off. 
When I run the script manually it works, when I let crontab do it only "on" seems to work. I can not figure out what I did wrong.

I've read some posts and included a shebang, made the file writable,...

on.py

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3
from gpiozero import OutputDevice
light = OutputDevice(2)
light.on()
```

off.py

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3
from gpiozero import OutputDevice
light = OutputDevice(2)
light.off()
```

at "`crontab -e`" i've written:

```
0 11 * * * /home/pi/Desktop/off.py
```

Comment: Did you remember to chmod +x them?

Comment: @JulioP.C. It probably wouldn't work started manually either. if not marked executable. Unless it was marked +x for owner but not for all users...

Comment: He could start it manually without assigning the executable flag, by invoking the python interpreter on the command line.

Comment: Both files are executable for "anyone" (right click -> properties -> permission)
I just noticed something.
When double clicking the file, I get a window with "execute", "open", ....
When I click "execute", it doesn't work. When I click open, Thonny opens, I click the green "run current script" button and it works.
Does this help?

Answer (score 0):

Trap the detailed text of the error, as python sees it.
This updated version of your cron should do the trick:

```
0 11 * * * /home/pi/Desktop/off.py 1> /tmp/myerr.txt 2>&1
```

...and when it fails again, use a text editor to see if an error message is in /tmp/myerr.txt.

The following suggestions will help if the error is a problem with python locating/executing your gpio library.

One way to tell python the location of the library you're using is with some like this:

```
PYTHONPATH=/foo/bar/baz python somescript.py somecommand
```

as detailed [in this well-voted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4580120/2377579).

Make sure to use absolute path(s) to files/folders in PYTHONPATH in both your cron invocation and your manual invocation;  this will eliminate the possibility that cron can't find your library because of a relative path issue.

As an alternaive to PYTHONPATH, you could use sys.path.append [as detailed here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4580130/2377579).

[This link](https://gpiozero.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) and [this link](https://gpiozero.readthedocs.io/en/stable/installing.html) may be helpful for gpiozero installation issus.

Comment: He is using absolute filepath. Just look at his crontab line

Comment: I edited my answer to clarify where I though the better pathing would help.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer. I'm not sure if I get what you're saying. Does it mean I don't write `from gpiozero import .....` but `from /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gpiozero import......` 
If that's what you mean: 1. it doesn't work, 2. This doesn't make sense to me. The script "on.py" is working with crontab. Both files are executable for "anyone" (right click -> properties -> permission)

Comment: I updated my comment with suggestions to get detailed text of the error, and how to avoid problems with python locating your gpio library.