# Run Python module from command line like in Pycharm

Tags: python, command-line, module, pycharm

I have a directory structure like this:

```
my_project
   .idea
   src
       config.ini
       method.py
       ... other py modules
```

When I open the project in PyCharm and run with the configuration below, it runs perfectly. It runs `src.method` as a module using an Anaconda 3 environment. The `src.method` module uses relative imports from other modules in `src` and takes `config.ini` as an argument.

I am trying to run the module in the same way through the Windows command line from `src` as the working directory

`C:\Users\deimos\Anaconda3\envs\cveureka\python.exe -m src.method "config.ini"`

but this gives a `ModuleNotFoundError`saying it could not find `src`. I tried replacing `src.method` with just `method` but that gives `ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package`.

I have also tried setting the `PYTHONPATH` before running the module with

```
setlocal
set PYTHONPATH=%2
```

like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4580120), but to no effect.

It there a way to set up the command line to replicate the way that PyCharm runs the module?

[image]

Comment: C:\Users\deimos\Anaconda3\envs\cveureka\python.exe -m C:/PATHTOPROJECT/my_project/src/method.py "config.ini"

Comment: @MachineLearner unfortunately this gives `Error while finding module specification for 'D:\\userdata\\deimos\\Dropbox\\work\\research\\seaice\\c20\\src\\method.py' (ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'D:\\userdata\\deimos\\Dropbox\\work\\research\\seaice\\c20\\src\\method')`

Comment: As far as I can see you are storing your project on another drive. This means that you need to first change your drive. The easiest way would be to take your project and move it to the same drive (not necessarily same folder) as your python.exe.

Comment: I tried that but unfortunately it didn't do anything