# cmake pybind11 testfile can't find the module created by the cmake file

Tags: python, c++, cmake, pytest, pybind11

I tried the cmake_example project provided by the pybind11 docs https://github.com/pybind/cmake_example. Running the cmake file worked and it created a folder named `cmake_example.dir` in the `build/x 64-Debug/CMakeFiles` folder. However that folder only contains another one named `src` and nothing else.

When trying to run the test `file test_basic.py` it gives me an error saying it cant find the module cmake_example. Probably because there wasn't any .pyd file created no?
Why is that the case and how can I fix this?

EDIT: The .pyd file exists now in the output directory (I just had to build after generating the cache), however the python test still cant import the module saying ModuleNotFoundError: No module named cmake_example

Comment: "Running the cmake file worked" - Do you mean that you run `cmake` (with some arguments)? That command just **configures** the project. For **building** the project, you need to run generator-specific command. E.g. on Linux it is usually `make`.

Comment: Generating the Cache and building the file works now. Importing the generated file doesn't -> `unresolved import "cmake_example"`
-> i imported it using `import cmake_example as m`

Comment: You probably need to point Python where to search your module. See e.g. that question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4580101/python-add-pythonpath-during-command-line-module-run

Comment: i have tried that using 
`import os
current_file_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
import sys
sys.path.append(current_file_path  + "../out//build/x64-Debug")
import cmake_example as m`
Didn't change anything sadly.