# How to use python packages from given directory, other than default directory?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, package

Let's say I've installed `torch` using `pip3` in my `user1`'s account.

```
user1@desktop:~$ pip3 show torch
Name: torch
Version: 1.11.0
Summary: Tensors and Dynamic neural networks in Python with strong GPU acceleration
Home-page: https://pytorch.org/
Author: PyTorch Team
Author-email: packages@pytorch.org
License: BSD-3
Location: /home/user1/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages
Requires: typing-extensions
Required-by: ogb, pytorch-lightning, torchaudio, torchmetrics, torchvision
```

As can be seen above, `pip3`-installed packages' location is `/home/user1/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages`.

Now, say that I want to run some python file using `sudo` privilege. (Assume that I can pass along the correct password when using `sudo` privilege.) In this case, however, it returns `ModuleNotFoundError` since `torch` is installed in my `user1`'s account, not in root user's.

```
user1@desktop:~$ sudo python3 toy_example.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "toy_example.py", line 1, in <module>
    import torch
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'torch'
```

When I attempt to run certain file with `sudo` privilege, how can I link python packages installed in ordinary user's account? (e.g., `torch`, which is installed in `/home/user1/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages` in the above example) I think it would be possible if I fix some environment variables, but couldn't figure it out.

Comment: Try `which python3` in user1's previlige, and run `sudo <output>` where <output> is result of first command.

Comment: @minolee Well it doesn't work, since result of `which python3` is same when ran from user1 and from root. Both results are `/usr/bin/python3`.

Comment: Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4580101/python-add-pythonpath-during-command-line-module-run this answer would help? `sudo PYTHONPATH=/home/user1/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages python3 toy_example.py`

Comment: @minolee The command works. You've just saved so much time for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@minolee 's comment solved the issue. The following command works fine for me.

```
sudo PYTHONPATH=/home/user1/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages python3 toy_example.py
```

Visit [Python - add PYTHONPATH during command line module run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4580101/python-add-pythonpath-during-command-line-module-run) for more help.