# running script in default python3 inside a embedded python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a script that runs inside a program that has embedded python (python from salome platform). I want to add some commands that are from a python library (meshio) that is not installed in the embedded one and I can not install on it anything. nevetheless I installed the library in the default python3 from my pc. This being said, the question is how can I call my default python3 from the embedded python?
some information:

1. I can not install meshio in salome python
2. I need to keep my main script inside the embedded salome python
3. meshio library i can (and did) isntalled in my python3 of the system
4. I can not install subprocess library in the embedded salome python

here are more details :
a. the external script is called VTKCreation.py, it is located in /home/franco/Desktop/VTKCreation.py
and looks like this:

```py
import meshio
def import_and_export_mesh(input_file, output_file):
    mesh = meshio.read(input_file)
    meshio.write(output_file, mesh)
    print(f"Mesh successfully imported from '{input_file}' and exported to '{output_file}'.")
input_file_path = "/home/franco/Desktop/Mesh_1.med"
output_file_path = "/home/franco/Desktop/Mesh_1.vtk"
import_and_export_mesh(input_file_path, output_file_path)
```

the other script is located in /home/franco/Desktop/embedded_script.py
and looks like this:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
print("Current working directory:", os.getcwd())
os.system('python3 ./Desktop/VTKCreation.py' )
os.system('python3 /home/franco/Desktop/VTKCreation.py' )
```

furthemore the external script, should read `/home/franco/Desktop/Mesh_1.med` which is there and create `/home/franco/Desktop/Mesh_1.vtk` which is being created.
lastly, if I run `python3 /home/franco/Desktop/VTKCreation.py` in the terminal `Mesh_1.vtk` is correctly created, if I run it from the embedded script inside salome platform using `exec(compile(open('/home/franco/Desktop/embedded_script.py', 'rb').read(), '/home/franco/Desktop/embedded_script.py', 'exec'))` it does not create the `Mesh_1.vtk` as expected

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Looks like you are over-complicating things. But I cannot say for sure before knowing your use case.

Comment: hello, I need to export my generated mesh in vtk format, and salome sadly does not support it, so I need to export it in .med format and then change it to vtk thats why I need meshio

Comment: I think I did not phrase my question correctly. I wanted to know what is wrong with exporting it in `.med` and then manually running the Python script from your system console instead of using an embedded terminal.

Comment: oh my bad. the thing is that the vtk mesh is an imput for another software and its output i need to re plugged to my original script so it continue running. it is quite farfetched but for the moment it is the 'simplest' workflow

Comment: Got it. I googled a bit about salome. You can install any python3 package using the `pip install` in the integrated console. That way you will not have to call the default `python`

Comment: thanks for your help, I might be missing something, I know that I can install packages in salome by using `./salome shell` and then I can install such as with pip install, but as salome has an old python, it is dependency hell, and the original library I want to use that is `pip install meshio[all]` does not install properly it fails at the installation of `h5py` . and using the scripts inside classic python3 i can not as the libraries from salome are bundled inside of its python only

Comment: Ok. What happens if bat script as shown here and then use `os.system('pythonpath.bat <path_to_default_python> ./Desktop/VTKCreation.py' )`.  You can find `<path_to_default_python>` by running `where python` in `cmd`.https://stackoverflow.com/a/4580120/20762025

Comment: sorry, I am not sure of understanding what you want me to do.... I imagine that for `where python` you meant `which python3`? which gives as output /usr/bin/python3 but I am not 100% sure what you want me to do. use this line inside my embedded_script?
`PYTHONPATH=/usr/bin/python3 python3 /home/franco/Desktop/VTKCreation.py`?

Comment: I though you were using windows. coz I saw `Desktop`. Try running your script with `PYTHONPATH=/usr/bin/python3 python3 /home/franco/Desktop/VTKCreation.py` from the embedded terminal

Comment: it is a python embedded terminal, so I imagine that you mean to add to the embedded script something like this `os.system('PYTHONPATH=/usr/bin/python3 python3 /home/franco/Desktop/VTKCreation.py')` ? if thats the case it does not work.
here is the output to the embedded code if I use that command inside of it.
https://codeshare.io/1YJmQB

Comment: Yes. That's what I meant. I wasn't sure if it would work. You might have to just suck up and do the thing you want to do manually or build meshio from source for the embedded terminal.